# How do I prevent Compass from outputting .sass-cache folder using Grunt

Tags: caching, sass, gruntjs, compass

I have a .sass-cache folder that is being auto generated. Trying to figure out how not to let it generate it at all. To be more clear, I don't want the .sass-cache folder.

I've tried several approaches but can't seem to keep it from generating.

Here's a couple approaches attempted:

- noCache: false or true
- config.rb file with: asset_cache_buster = :none
- config.rb file with: cache = false

Here is what my watch is doing:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

watch: {
    scripts: {
        files: ['assets/js/*.js'],
        tasks: ['concat', 'uglify', 'copy', 'clean'],
        options: {
            spawn: false
        }
    },
    scss: {
        files: ['assets/scss/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['compass', 'cssmin'],
    }
},
```

then later on, here is what Compass is doing & a snippet of my tasks:

```
compass: {
    development: {
        options: {
            config: './config.rb',
            sassDir: 'assets/scss',
            cssDir: 'assets/css'
        }
    }
},

clean:{
    build: {
    }
}
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
grunt.registerTask(
    'build',
    'Compiles all the assets and copies the files to the build directory.',
    ['less', 'compass', 'cssmin', 'concat', 'uglify', 'copy', 'clean']
);
};
```

here is what I'm trying in my config.

```
if File.file?( './.nosasscache' )
    asset_cache_buster = :none
    cache = false # Uncomment to disable cache.
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting `cache = false` in your `config.rb` should be enough.  You could try disabling all caching:

```
asset_cache_buster = :none
cache = false
```

If that doesn't work you could always run a clean to remove the folder.(see link)

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass#clean

Comment: It's still not happening. I even tried, grunt compass clean, within the terminal and it still generates the .sass-cache folder. I also tried adding compass-clean as a task, but doesn't seem to work. I'm obviously not doing something right. I am also being sure that I kill the terminal task and start it back up to be sure the changes take effect.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Sass from the command line, you can add the `--no-cache` flag:

`sass --no-cache input.scss output.css`